# Is it possible to have 2 different git repositories for the same project, 1 base, 1 override?

Tags: git, maven, maven-3

I was wondering if it's possible to have a project set up like this:

1. You have `repositoryA`, where you host your base project.
2. You have another repository for `clientRepositoryA`, where you do modifications or overrides on `repositoryA` codes.
3. When you invoke maven install, it downloads from `repositoryA` and overrides it with files from `clientRepositoryA`.
4. The final artefact is not a merge, but instead `clientRepositoryA` is an override. So if there is no file in `clientRepositoryA`, then the app runs on `repositoryA` code alone.
5. Once `repositoryA` is updated, it's possible that `clientRepositoryA` will be broken and needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me re-imagine what you are trying to do.

Instead of having 2 local git repositories, why not separate them using 2 branches, each will have it's separate commits, but still they are linked and can borrow commits from each others,

and as of the pushing, you could use 2 separate remotes, so then you can decide which branch you want to push to which remote, keep in mind that you can instruct a branch when creating it to have a different name on the remote side, like having `client1` local branch that tracks `master` remote branch in `origin1`.. same for `origin2` for example.

Hope I'm making sense to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have just one problem, actually my project is a multi-maven project and I only want to override 1. With your suggestion it's required to push all the projects in the other remote repo right?

Comment: No, you can push only 1 branch to the other repo, a very detailed push could be like this ( but you can simplify it by settings ): `git push client2 version2:master` this would push `version2` to `client2`'s `master`

Comment: The problem is in repoA I have 1 multi-maven project which has 5 modules. I only want to override 1 module (moduleX) and push in a remote repository. I'm guessing it's not possible to override just moduleX right?